# Merge Multiple QCAR Projects with One Main Project

Tags: android, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

i am working in Augmented Reality and i`ve made some demo Projects Using QCAR sample Projects 
they are working one individually, but i want to combine them in one Main project and give user an option to select any of the following project at its own 
but it creating a problem as all the QCAR projects have a folder named "libs" an d sub folder to to are "armeabi" & "armeabi-v7a" that loads its own data and can not be renamed 
is there any way to handle this issue

Thank You .....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing hit and trial method of few hours i`ve come to this and worked successfully 
do the following steps

> Use the QCAR Project as Library
>
> ```
> Add the Project (QCAR) in main Project
>
>  Copy the Files from each QCAR Project`s libs folder into main Porject libs folder like this
> ```

source folder (Image Target) copy "armeabi" & "armeabi-v7a" and paste it in to destination project (main project) libs folder

now if you want to add another project of QCAr just copy the relevent files from both above mentioned folders

> e.g. "Virtual Button" just coy the following files in to the libs folder of the main project
>
> ```
> libs=> armeabi=>libVirtualButtons.so &
>
> libs=> armeabi-v7a=>libVirtualButtons.so &
> ```

and so on